# Can I schedule a function with Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-worker

I want to execute a function every midnight on my PWA, without using Web Push, in the background or when chrome doesn't in execution. How I can do it?

Comment: could you tell us what you have already tried?

Comment: On a client device…? Which might not even be turned on…? That won't be very reliable either way…

Comment: I think push notifications are the only appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: I've already tried to use push notification, but I'd not like to use it. Could be other methods?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use Background Sync API?

**Sources:**

1. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync
2. https://ponyfoo.com/articles/backgroundsync